# Force SQLite to fail on bad database path

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I make sure that a connection to an SQLite database fails if I try to make a connection to a database which doesn't exist, or an error is thrown in the code to show that this db did not prior exist?

I'm currently using Python3 to connect to my SQLite database, however, if I use a path to a db which doesn't exist, SQLite creates a database of that name and forms a connection to it.

I can see why this would be helpful in most cases. However, I can't test to see if SQlite has made a proper connection as no error is thrown when this situation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.4 or later, the [connect() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) accepts URI filenames, which allow to [specify a different open mode](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html#recognized_query_parameters):

```
db = sqlite3.connect('file:/some/where/stuff.db?mode=rw', uri=True)
```